# Can we use RadRibbonBar in wpf without RadWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, telerik-radribbonbar

In my project I want to use RadRibbon control. All the examples I came across show the use of RadRibbon control inside a RadWindow. My Qusetion is that Can we use RadRibbon control in our normal Wpf project.

Answer (score 1):

RadRibbon is a control and so should be able to be embedded in any other control.

[Here is an example](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radribbonbar-howto-using-radribbonbar-prism-region2.html) of it being used with a Grid.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [Telerik WPF Controls Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/wpf/) yet? They have at least one example without a RadWindow.

Also, since the RadRibbonView is "just" another control you'd place it into your Xaml file like you'd do with every other control.

Answer (score 0):

Found out a good getting started article at http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radribbonbar-getting-started.html. The answer is yes you can use RadRibbonbar without RadWindow.